# model property is not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am making a simple knockout app, but I am getting an error "Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: gpaBasedScolarship is not defined; Bindings value: visible: gpaBasedScolarship"

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("/api/Values", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
            function studentModel(name, number, age, gpa) {
                var self = this;
                self.studentName = name;
                self.studentNumber = number;
                self.age = age;
                self.gpa = ko.observable(gpa);
                self.gpaBasedScolarship = ko.computed(function () {
                    if (gpa > 3)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;   
                });
            }
            function studentViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                //editable data
                self.students = ko.observableArray(data);
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new studentViewModel());
    });
});
```

What gives?

PS: My html is...

```
<div id="body">
    <div data-bind="foreach:students">
        <h1>Student</h1>
    <div><input type="text" data-bind="value:studentName"/></div>
    <div><input type="text" data-bind="value:studentNumber"/></div>
    <div><input type="text" data-bind="value:age"/></div>
    <div>
        <p><input type="text" data-bind="value:gpa"/></p>
        <p data-bind="visible: gpaBasedScolarship"><input type="text" data-bind=""/></p>
    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In addition to the answer below, move your ko.applyBindings statement OUTSIDE of your api callback.  Your HTML inside the `<div data-bind="foreach...">` will still be visible until the applyBindings is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told knockout to map your `data` into a `studentModel`.

```
var mappedData = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
    return new studentModel(...);
});
self.students = ko.obserbableArray(mappedData);
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but without this line: <p data-bind="visible: gpaBasedScolarship"><input type="text" data-bind=""/></p> the whole things works.

Comment: @IlyaNemtsev its because your data might have those as a properties on the object, but your view model has it, which isn't getting used.

Comment: It wasn't working in the first place because your `gpaBasedScolarship` property is a computed of your `gpa` property. Without mapping your data, your `gpa` property would be a normal property, not an observable one, and your `gpaBasedScolarship` wouldn't work. When you map your array objects, you're creating one observable for each `gpa` property, and then your `gpaBasedScolarship` will work as well ;)